# Jboss 7 not Creating Persistence Unit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, persistence

I use Jboss 7 , hibernate 4.1.5 FINAL and Spring 3.1.2 for my application

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Virtuoso] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        ... 3 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 9 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:189)
    ... 26 more
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
       <module name="org.hibernate"></module>
    </exclusions>

  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Virtuoso" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >


    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</non-jta-data-source>

    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

i am not knowing where i am going wrong..My Persistent unit not getting started.

Comment: why exactly are you excluding hibernate from your deployment? You see, you are having problems with the deployment of hibernate.

Comment: i am doing that because JBoss 7 has inbuild persistence hibernate 4 provider to avoid that and use my applications hibernate version i am excluding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejb3 - persistence jar was present in my lib folder which was conflicting with mu hibernate jpa 2.0 jar . so i added scope provided in my pom.xml . after that class cast exception went away.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're attempting to use Hibernate 4.x packaged in your application, you should instead be setting the `jboss.as.jpa.providerModule` property to `application` [in your persistence.xml configuration file](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-Persistenceunitproperties).

You're better off replacing the Hibernate 4.0 module in AS7, [with a newer version though](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion). That way, you dont need to package a JPA provider in your application.